# how to bind resourcedirectory source property using binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

### Scenario

I have the following set of code in my `window.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="MD.UI.EntryPoint.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:UICore="http://schemas.MasterData.io/Core/"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/MD.UI.Core;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
                <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="{DynamicResource }"></ResourceDictionary>-->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="btnShow" Content="Show" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="329,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83" Height="22" Click="btnShow_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If you are familiar with XAML than you can understand that the `Generic.xaml` is defined in a separate project (`dll`) name `MD.UI.Core` is referenced in this project and it's **all working fine**. Means the `Generic.xaml` theme is working fine.

### Problem

The `MD.UI.Core` also has `http://schemas.MasterData.io/Core/` `XmlnsDefinition` used here as:

```
 xmlns:UICore="http://schemas.MasterData.io/Core/"
```

So, while I have already defined `xmlns:UICore` inside `window.xaml` further I don't want to use `/MD.UI.Core;component/Themes/Generic.xaml` anymore. Which I want to do is, by using `xmlns` I want to bind the `ResourceDirectory.Source` property something like:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="{DynamicResource }"></ResourceDictionary>
```

#### EDIT

Actually I want to direct use the `UICore` reference like

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="{DynamicResource UICore:component/Themes/Generic.xaml}"></ResourceDictionary>
```

Or `something` else but using `Binding` expression of `XAML markup`.

I don't have idea. How to define the above?
Can you please help me?

Comment: How about simply putting the URL in the `Source` property? Nothing fancy, just the URL on it's own.

Comment: Do you know @MikeEason that `source` of `ResourceDirectory` is a `dependency property`? what is it's `uses` than?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. But `Source` is a dependency property of type `System.Uri`, so you should be able to just do this: `Source="http://schemas.MasterData.io/Core/"`.

Comment: How to specify `/Themes/Generic.xaml` there .. can you please post your thought as answer .. so that we can discuss on it in more detail

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish here - do you want to not reference said dictionary once  `xmlns:UICore="..."` mapping is declared? If so, why don't you just remove the resource dictionary reference? Namespace mappings are not runtime properties - each namespace mapping prefix referenced in _XAML_ needs to be defined before parsing, otherwise that _XAML_ is not valid (this rule is "inherited" from _XML_). Perhaps I misunderstood your goal - if that's the case, could you please clarify?

Comment: I'd like to confirm my understanding. Am I right that you simply want to be able to dynamically select which theme (a resource dictionary) should be used? Once it will be the one from the A.dll, another time from B.dll... If so, do you have a requirement to do so in XAML?

Comment: Are you just trying to save typing...? Hope not...

Comment: @MichałKomorowski please look on my edit

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that what you want to do is to be able to select a theme (a resource dictionary) dynamically. I usually do so in C#. For example let's assume that we have 2 themes. The first one is embedded in the current assembly and the second comes from the external one. Let's call them *Internal.xaml* and *External.xaml* from *External.dll*. Now we can write the following method:

```
private static void SetStyle(bool useInternal)
{
    var res = Application.Current.Resources;
    res.MergedDictionaries.Clear();

    if (useInternal)
        res.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Internal.xaml")
        });
    else
        res.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/External;component/External.xaml")
        });
}
```

This method is simplified because assumes that there can be only one item in `MergedDictionaries` collection. However, it shows an idea. In practise you can add/remove resources to/from `MergedDictionaries` collection accordingly.

It is also worth pointing that `SetStyle` method above uses the global resource dictionary. If you want, you can do the same with local dictionaries, for example for a particular window or even a control.

Comment: please have a look on my `edit part` .. i appreciate the way you try ..but my question is not related to this